# How does full-text search snowball algorithm interpret words of an unspecified language

Tags: sqlite, full-text-search, snowball, fts5

I build a full-ext search index with sqlite and don't understand what is going on internally when i'm scanning documents contain few languages.

For example, i describe a programming topic i'm learning **in Russian** and add into the description code blocks with programming language syntax statements and comments which are obviously **in English**.

Let's consider the example **document.txt**

```
Вывод хранимых данных производится следующей командой

import storage
def main()  # Comments just to represent an example
    print(storage.data)
```

As you can see **document.txt** consists of two languages.

I use the [snowball tokenizer](https://github.com/abiliojr/fts5-snowball)(it reuses standard [sowball library](https://github.com/snowballstem/snowball)) to index the completed documents explicitly specifying `CREATE TABLE documents USING FTS5(text, tokenize='snowball russian');` and it handles it with no issues. So here is a point why? The documents contain English words and later on, the index contains **English stems** along with **Russian stems**, i can search `команда` or `commenting` successfully. Is it how things work?

Comment: *snowball* isn't one of the standard FTS5 tokenizers. Maybe include a link to its implementation?

Comment: You guess it fully based on an algorithm implementation? My standpoint it's a common issue for all the implementations and it's solution is also should be common, but that's my assumption only and i want to figure it out. 
Link to the implementation is added.